# Multiple assignments in a single select

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I have written a function in PostgreSQL where I wish to assign multiple values to variables using a single select statement. I have declared a few variables and using a select I wish to assign values to those variables in the body of the function. Please find below the body of the function:

```
BEGIN        
select SUM(quantity) into v_quantity, MAX(price) into v_price from trade where id=4;
END
```

When I compile the function I am getting the following error

```
ERROR:  "max" is not a known variable
LINE 20:     select SUM(quantity) into v_quantity, max(price) into v_...
```

What could be the reason? Does PostgreSQL not allow multiple assignments through a single select?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. To make it work you should have only a single select list and a single `INTO` clause like so:

```
BEGIN        
  select SUM(quantity), MAX(price) into v_quantity, v_price from trade where id=4;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable of type *record* instead:

```
...
declare
    rec record;
begin      
    select sum(quantity) as v_quantity, max(price) as v_price into rec from trade where id=4;
    if rec.v_quantity > 100 then
    ...
```